# unable to store multiple images in Django

Tags: python, django

I am doing an hotel booking web app in Django. The problem is I have written the models perfectly with foreign key references. The main problem I got is with this [reference](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/22/django-multiple-file-upload-using-ajax.html).

In my web app, I want a progress bar on uploading images. For that I have included code from the given reference, but the problem is the images don't get stored when I upload them.

**Here are my models:**

```
hotel_rating_choices  = (
('1','1'),
('2','2'),
('3','3'),
('4','4'),
('5','5'),
('6','6'),
('7','7'),
)

class Hotel(models.Model):

    Hotel_Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    no_of_rooms = models.IntegerField()
    room_price = models.IntegerField()
    rating = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=hotel_rating_choices, default=3)
    hotel_main_img = models.FileField(upload_to='hotel_images/')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Hotel_Name

class Hotel_image(models.Model):

    hotel_img = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'hotel_images/', blank = True, null = True)
    hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="hotel_images")
```

**Here is my form:**

```
class add_hotel(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Hotel
    fields = ('Hotel_Name', 'location', 'rating','no_of_rooms', 'room_price', 'hotel_main_img', )

    widgets = {
        'hotel_main_img' : forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True})
    }
```

**Here is my view:**

```
class BasicUploadView(FormView):

template_name = 'photos/basic_upload/index.html'
model = Hotel
form_class = add_hotel
success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    form = add_hotel
    return render(
            self.request,
            template_name = self.template_name,
            context={'form' : form}
         )

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    form = self.form_class(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():

        Hotel_Name = form.cleaned_data['Hotel_Name']
        location = form.cleaned_data['location']
        no_of_rooms = form.cleaned_data['no_of_rooms']
        room_price = form.cleaned_data['room_price']
        rating = form.cleaned_data['rating']
        hotel_main_img = form.cleaned_data['hotel_main_img']
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        uploaded_at = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        user = request.user

        hotel_object = Hotel.objects.create(Hotel_Name = Hotel_Name, location = location, no_of_rooms = no_of_rooms, room_price = room_price, rating = rating,
                                            hotel_main_img = hotel_main_img, uploaded_at = uploaded_at, user = user)

        hotel_images_list = form.files.getlist('hotel_main_img')
        for image in hotel_images_list:
            Hotel_image.objects.create(hotel_img = image, hotel = hotel_object)

        return redirect('home')

    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

**The images_list contains only one image and the remaining images are not storing.**

**Here is my main culprit template page where I've got the problem:**

```
<div align="center">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary js-upload-photos">
  Upload photos
</button>
  <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="hotel_main_img" multiple
       style="display: none;"
       data-url="{% url 'basic_upload' %}"
       data-form-data='{"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>
</div>
```

I didn't upload the complete HTML page, but the main part is with this and the problem is with this only, as specified in the blog, I have given the name as **hotel_main_img** but it's not working in my case.

Here is my page:

[image]

When I upload through the browse button, the main image is uploading successfully, but when I get uploading through the upload photos button, the images don't get stored. I don't know where the images are uploading. When I debug through `ipdb`, in the `hotel_main_img` there is only one image in it and the rest of them are missing. Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that on your `Hotel` model you have `hotel_main_img` and it's defined to be `models.FileField(upload_to='hotel_images/'). So not only is it not an`ImageField`, it's a`FileField`...but also it's not a list of images...it's a single file upload that is being rendered for your form and the same for the automatic form handling

You are going to need to create a formset containing inline forms for your related `Hotel_image` object. Then you can allow multiple images to be uploaded.

Comment: No, when i upload multiple images through browse button, hotel_main_img contains multiple images in it, its working, but not working through html upload photos button, how can i make that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by uploading multiple images through "browse button"...but I can tell you that you have it setup incorrectly. You rmodel is only setup to store a single `hotel_main_img` and as a result your form is only setup to handle a single `hotel_main_img`.

Comment: Whatever you are doing on your front-end and sending up in your POST request doesn't matter at this point...your view and forms are not setup to accept multiple images. Your model is ok...but the field that will accept multiple images is `hotel_images`, not `hotel_main_img`.

Comment: It is storing the multiple images when i uploaded , and i can also see them in my database, i provided the reference in my question, in that they mentioned we can also upload multiple images through a FileField, please once go through that, and the problem is with upload photos button.How can i connect it to my model. please be patient with my problem :)